# .htaccess RewriteCond for a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a website on one domain and it has another domain mapped to it. I have a .htaccess RewriteCond like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.additional-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.main-domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

This obviously means that any pages accessed by going to www.additional-domain.com will redirect to the correct page on www.main-domain.com.

What I would like to know is; can I keep this rule but have certain pages **not** redirect? so for page /this-page.html if the user accessed www.additional-domain.com/this-page.html then they are **not** redirected to www.main-domain.co.uk/this-page.html

Is this even possible? Thanks.

-------- EDIT --------

I neglected to mention that for those additional pages I want the redirect to work in reverse.

So if someone accessed www.main-domain.co.uk/this-page.html then they would be redirected to www.additional-domain.co.uk/this-page.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add extra conditions to your redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/this-page\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/this-page2\.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.additional-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.main-domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```