# Domain Alias to specific page on my WP website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to ask you about use of alias and how to set it up in htaccess.

I have a specific page on my WP - domain.com/apple/ and I would like to add a alias to this page so it would be accessible though this domain - apple.com. I want to mention that I need to use alias just on this specific page and not on a different ones on my website.

Is there any rule that I can use in htaccess that would solve this problem?

Thank you guys for your comments & much love!
Filip

Comment: Please find answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950128/htaccess-rewritecond-for-a-specific-page

Comment: The first thing you need to do, is set up your web server to handle that alternative domain, and route it into the same project directory. This is not something you can do on the .htaccess level, this needs to be done inside the VirtualHost configuration for your existing domain.